# Why event.keyCode not working in ng-keyup?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
ng-keyup="if (event.keyCode == 13) setCurrent(pagination.navigatevalue);"
```

this works fine with onkeyup but not ng-keyup..Am I missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event object is available as `$event` in *ng* event directives expressions. Another problem with your code is that you [can't use control statements](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) like `if-else`. Simple solution is to use logical [AND operator `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation).

Your code will look like this:

```
ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && setCurrent(pagination.navigatevalue)"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$event` instead of `event`:

```
ng-keyup="if ($event.keyCode == 13) setCurrent(pagination.navigatevalue);"
```

Angular exposes a jQuery `$event` object in template, see [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)